# why am i getting invalid syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

generate 10 random integers 1-100 store them in a list. Use a loop. Use a second loop to process the list. In this latter loop, display all numbers in the list and determine the sum of the odd numbers and the sum of the even numbers. Display these sums after the second loop has ended. what's wrong?

```
import random 

randomList = [] # create list 

sumEven= sumOdd = 0 

for x in range(10):

    r = random.randint(1,100) 
    print(r), 
    randomList.append(r) 
for x in range(len(randomList)): 

    if (randomList[x]%2 == 0): #even number 
        sumEven += randomList[x] 
    else: 
        sumOdd += randomList[x] 

print "\nSum of even numbers =",sumEven 

print "Sum of odd numbers =",sumOdd
```

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3.x.  You need to use parenthesis:  `print(...)`.

Comment: but right now when i run the program its not adding the sums?

Comment: @ANNABELL,looks like your classmate has already asked a question on the subject,  have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265103/python-stuck-on-skipping-range-values-for-the-sum-of-a-randint-list/26265661#26265661

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please post the **full error message**.

That being said, `print` is a function. You should use parentheses with it.

https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function